# http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call StatusOK

Tags: go

In my code, I've a loop that processing set of files (based on what available at pre-specified folder), and based on the output of each processed file, some info is sent to the client, so I wrote the below:

```golang
    for i, file := range files {
        uniqueSlice := unique(matches)
        output = Output{MSG: "ok", File: file, Skills: uniqueSlice}
        data, err := json.Marshal(output)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) // -< Error from here
        w.Write(data)
    }
```

Above working correctly if the folder has a single file, but if has more than one, I got the error: `http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call`
I understood the error is due to using `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` which can not be used more than once to be set, but I need it to be set for the client to process the returned data.

How can I fix this code, so that I can return data directly to the client upon processing each file.

**UPDATE**
If I remove `http.StatusOK` as recommended in the comments below, then I get the returned as plain text not as JSON!

Comment: HTTP response contains a header and body. Once you start writing the body, the header is already sent, so any changes you make to the header are lost. You are sending multiple files to the client in a single response. You can only set the header once, not for each file.

Comment: The status is the first line of any response, so if you've sent data the status must already have been sent. There's no point setting `http.StatusOK` here.

Comment: @BurakSerdar kindly see my update

Comment: @JimB  kindly see my update

Comment: Did you write to `w` before this for loop?

Comment: Removing the `WriteHeader` cannot effect the `Content-Type` header, but if you are now writing the header before this, setting another header of course will have no effect. Please create a [mre]

Comment: you got to learn your basics https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview HTTP headers can be set once only per request or response. If you try to send multiple time the headers, the response is misinterpreted by the clent. Currently your server detects the mistake and tries to give you an hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just concatenate JSON documents together and expect the result to be valid json encoded.  You'll have to put your `output` objects in an array and then output that array once at the end, otherwise the response won't be valid json.

If you output objects individually like your code did, the final data will look like

```
{"MSG": "ok", "File": "...", "Skills": [...]}{"MSG": "ok", "File": "...", "Skills": [...]}{"MSG": "ok", "File": "...", "Skills": [...]}
```

Each one of those outputs is valid by itself, but the entire output with the objects just concatenated together, is *not*.

Ideally, when outputting json to a stream like an HTTP response, instead of storing it in an intermediate buffer (`data`) for you, use `json.NewEncoder(w)` where `w` is the http response writer.  Streaming is almost always better than rendering to a variable.

```
    var outputs = make([]Output,0,len(files)
    for i, file := range files {
        uniqueSlice := unique(matches)
        outputs = append(outputs, Output{MSG: "ok", File: file, Skills: uniqueSlice})
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(outputs); err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your explanation.